# Help with jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following markup

```
<div id="FirstDiv">
  <div class="MyClass">
      <span>
           <a href="#">link 1</a>
           <a href="#">link 2</a>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="SecondDiv">
  <div class="MyClass">
      <span>
           <a href="#">link 1</a>
           <a href="#">link 2</a>
      </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I select alla the `<a>` tag elements inside the DIV "SecondDiv"?

Actually I am doing

```
$(".MyClass > a").click(function (event) {
```

but this would select also links of the first div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#SecondDiv a')
```

This uses the ID of the `SecondDiv` element, and selects [all descendant](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `<a>` elements.

You were using [the `>` child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/), which would only select immediate children. And you're right that it would select from  both `.MyClass` elements.

Another possibility would be to place [a `.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) on the `SecondDiv` element to match clicks against the nested `<a>` elements.

```
$('#SecondDiv').delegate( 'a', 'click', function() {
      // your code
});
```

---

**EDIT:** In reference to your comment below, you can limit it to `<a>` elements in the `.MyClass` element by placing that in the selector.

```
$('#SecondDiv .MyClass a')
```

Now any `<a>` elements that do not descend from `.MyClass` will not be included.

Comment: Is there a way to use also the Myclass selector like `$('#SecondDiv .MyClass a')`

Comment: @Lorenzo - Yes, if there will be other `<a>` elements under `SecondDiv` that are not also under `.MyClass`, then that selector would eliminate those.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the ID Selector (#) over here instead of the class selector (.)

```
$("#SecondDiv a").click(function (event) {
```

Read more about [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) and [Class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#SecondDiv a").click(function(){
  alert("Hi-o");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#SecondDiv").find("a").click(function(event) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

why dontb yu use id of second div ('#second div')

or

http://api.jquery.com/children/